# Will Alibaba stock split in US market?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I know this is a rookie question. Please help because I just could not find an answer to this question. I am only asking this question because currently, I'm holding BABA and I'm using a stop loss. Therefore My understanding is if the split took place then my stop loss will be triggered, which I do not want.

I came to know that on 15th July 2019, the decision for a 1 to 8 split has been made. And this split will happen before July 15th, 2020. But since then there is no update on this ( at least I could not find it). [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/key-statistics?p=BABA) is not showing the date of the last split. So, I believe that split is yet to happen. However, I also came to know from some people that the split has been made already ( I do not have any credible source for that). Any insight on this will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Limit orders are adjusted for corporate events like stock splits (see FINRA Rule 5330) and therefore they are not triggered.

A  forward or reverse split has no effect on the value of your equity position.

Answer (score 0):

BABA split stock ahead of HK IPO listing hence why their value in that market is 1/8 the price of stock in US (currency adjusted). Would also expect a higher multiple in HK market w/ a possible disconnect in US with negative trade sentiment.

https://www.cnbc.com/2019/07/16/alibaba-stock-split-ahead-of-reported-hong-kong-ipo.html